# Spread observation which starts in one time over multiple rows to the end of the another time

Tags: r, time-series

I have time series data

```
        start_date_time    ...   process_duration_in_hours           end_date_time  
    2019-01-01 05:37:19    ...                       28,78     2019-01-02 10:24:24 
    2019-01-01 03:15:01    ...                       12,00     2019-01-01 15:15:01
```

where `...` is some features

I need to get data in the next form:

```
    start_date   ...   process_duration_in_hours
    2019-01-01   ...                       18,37
    2019-01-01   ...                       12,00
    2019-01-02   ...                       10,41
```

If I have an observation where `process_duration_in_hours` is longer than the remainder of a day, I want to spread this observation to the next day preserving all `...` features and change `process_duration_in_hours` value, which have to be equal the remainder of process duration in the next day. Also it is possible that process takes more than one day.

Answer (score 1):

Could do:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df$start_date_time <- as.POSIXct(df$start_date_time)
df$end_date_time <- as.POSIXct(df$end_date_time)

df <- setDT(df)[, `:=` (reps = pmax(1, floor(process_duration_in_hours / 24) + 1), id = .I)][
  , df[df[, rep(.I, reps)]]][
    reps > 1, process_duration_in_hours := {
      process_duration_in_hours[.N] <- difftime(end_date_time[.N], floor_date(end_date_time[.N], "day"), units = "hours");
      process_duration_in_hours[1] <- difftime(ceiling_date(start_date_time[1], "day", change_on_boundary = TRUE), start_date_time[1], units = "hours");
      process_duration_in_hours[process_duration_in_hours > 24] <- 24;
      round(process_duration_in_hours, 2)
    }, by = id][, start_date_time := as.Date(substr(start_date_time, 1, 10)) + (0:(.N - 1)), by = id][, c("reps", "id", "end_date_time") := NULL]
```

I've used slightly more complicated data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  start_date_time = c(
    "2019-01-01 05:37:19",
    "2019-01-01 03:15:01",
    "2019-01-02 04:00:00",
    "2019-01-05 00:00:00"
  ),
  process_duration_in_hours = c(28.78, 12.00, 56.00, 50.00),
  end_date_time = c(
    "2019-01-02 10:24:24",
    "2019-01-01 15:15:01",
    "2019-01-04 12:00:00",
    "2019-01-07 02:00:00"
  ),
  random_col = c("blabla", "dddd", "dddd", "eeee")
)

df

      start_date_time process_duration_in_hours       end_date_time random_col
1 2019-01-01 05:37:19                     28.78 2019-01-02 10:24:24     blabla
2 2019-01-01 03:15:01                     12.00 2019-01-01 15:15:01       dddd
3 2019-01-02 04:00:00                     56.00 2019-01-04 12:00:00       dddd
4 2019-01-05 00:00:00                     50.00 2019-01-07 02:00:00       eeee
```

Output:

```
   start_date_time process_duration_in_hours random_col
1:      2019-01-01                     18.38     blabla
2:      2019-01-02                     10.41     blabla
3:      2019-01-01                     12.00       dddd
4:      2019-01-02                     20.00       dddd
5:      2019-01-03                     24.00       dddd
6:      2019-01-04                     12.00       dddd
7:      2019-01-05                     24.00       eeee
8:      2019-01-06                     24.00       eeee
9:      2019-01-07                      2.00       eeee
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution which uses `foverlaps()` to split the given time ranges in pieces of one day lengths and computes the `process_duration` for each of the pieces.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
# create vector of start dates
start_date <- setDT(df)[, seq(floor_date(min(start_date_time), "day"), 
                              max(end_date_time),
                              by = "1 day")]
# create keyed data.table with start and end of each day
day_grid <- data.table(start_date, 
                       end = start_date + days(1), 
                       key = "start_date,end")
# find overlaps of ranges in df with day_grid
df2 <- foverlaps(df, day_grid, by.x = c("start_date_time", "end_date_time"))
# compute durations
df2[, process_duration := difftime(
  pmin(end, end_date_time),
  pmax(start_date, start_date_time),
  units = "hours")][
    # clean up
    process_duration > 0, .(start_date, process_duration, random_col)][
      # sort output
      order(start_date)]
```

> ```
>    start_date process_duration random_col
> 1: 2019-01-01   18.37806 hours     blabla
> 2: 2019-01-01   12.00000 hours       dddd
> 3: 2019-01-02   10.40667 hours     blabla
> 4: 2019-01-02   20.00000 hours       dddd
> 5: 2019-01-03   24.00000 hours       dddd
> 6: 2019-01-04   12.00000 hours       dddd
> 7: 2019-01-05   24.00000 hours       eeee
> 8: 2019-01-06   24.00000 hours       eeee
> 9: 2019-01-07    2.00000 hours       eeee
> ```

This approach has the advantage that it can be easily adapted to different time grids, e.g., hours, weeks, or months.

The `difftime` object has the `units` attribute. Therefore, the column name was abbreviated to `process_duration`.

#### Data

For comparison, the enhanced dataset of [arg0naut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54817110/3817004) is being used. Character datetimes are coerced to `POSIXct` right away by `ymd_hms()`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  start_date_time = ymd_hms(c(
    "2019-01-01 05:37:19",
    "2019-01-01 03:15:01",
    "2019-01-02 04:00:00",
    "2019-01-05 00:00:00"
  )),
  process_duration_in_hours = c(28.78, 12.00, 56.00, 50.00),
  end_date_time = ymd_hms(c(
    "2019-01-02 10:24:24",
    "2019-01-01 15:15:01",
    "2019-01-04 12:00:00",
    "2019-01-07 02:00:00"
  )),
  random_col = c("blabla", "dddd", "dddd", "eeee")
)
```